# Marklogic - highlighting cts:element-attribute-range-query output

Tags: xml, highlighting, marklogic

i am doing a `cts:element-attribute-range-query` and the results from it is working fine. But highlighting is not working for the output result. When i referred the search guide

http://developer.marklogic.com/pubs/4.2/books/search-dev-guide.pdf

i could see that `cts:element-attribute-*-query` outputs will not be suitable for `cts:highlight` function. I am using Marklogic 4.2. My application greatly depends on this highlighted output, Is there any way i can highlight the result output of `cts:element-attribute-range query`?

Comment: How exactly are you using `cts:element-attribute-range-query` and `cts:highlight`. A small code snippet (preferably a working isolated example) would help a lot. Your principle might be allright, but the function usage wrong..

Answer (score 0):

You could try `cts:walk` instead of `cts:highlight`. During the walk, look for nodes where `cts:contains` returns true for the attribute portion of your query. Then you can highlight those nodes using whatever mechanism you like.

http://developer.marklogic.com/pubs/4.2/apidocs/SearchBuiltins.html#cts:walk has examples.

Comment: Could you please provide an example, how to use `cts:contains` with `cts:walk` to highlight a text present in attribute.