# How to highlight text present in attribute in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic, highlighting

I have read the below document.

http://developer.marklogic.com/pubs/4.2/books/search-dev-guide.pdf

I could see that `cts:highlight` do not work on `cts:element-attribute-*-queries`.

I am looking for a work around for this.

Is there any other way to highlight text present in attributes when cts query match the attribute text?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259253/marklogic-highlighting-ctselement-attribute-range-query-output

Comment: Also, unless you are using version 4.2, I would look at the more recent publications since the current version is 9.0

Comment: @MichaelGardner I am using ML version 8.  I have seen the mentioned link and asked for an example as I don't see any example in the shared link mentioned in the answer. 
Could you please give an example.

Comment: Please also provide the link of "more recent publications" (ML 9)

Comment: All recent versions of the MarkLogic documentation are available on docs.marklogic.com.